# Jax-ws exception serialization failure

Tags: java, exception, soap, jax-ws

I'm facing an issues which I cannot find a solution too (or I'm tackling the wrong way). When certain exceptions are generated from my service it appears the serialization is failing. This results in getting a wrapped exception which is a pain as calling clients receive a poor error and I imagine I'm loosing useful info from the original exception.

In the bellow example its an S3 bucket access issue, but I have had similar problems with some SQL exceptions.

It would be useful if I could keep my services for intervening directly. The ideal would be to add some custom exception serialization code.

```
> com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.DataConverterException:
> Failure serializing
> "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client
> received SOAP Fault from server: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3;
> Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: AAAAAAAAAAAA)
> Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of
> the failure." of type "class
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException" when mapping
> key "null" at
> com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.JsonDataConverter.throwDataConverterException(JsonDataConverter.java:90)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.JsonDataConverter.toData(JsonDataConverter.java:78)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.pojo.POJOActivityImplementation.throwActivityFailureException(POJOActivityImplementation.java:102)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.pojo.POJOActivityImplementation.execute(POJOActivityImplementation.java:67)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.generic.ActivityImplementationBase.execute(ActivityImplementationBase.java:46)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.SynchronousActivityTaskPoller.execute(SynchronousActivityTaskPoller.java:196)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.ActivityTaskPoller$2.run(ActivityTaskPoller.java:92)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Type id handling
> not implemented for type org.w3c.dom.Node (by serializer of type
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer) (through reference
> chain:
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException["fault"]) at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.mappingException(SerializerProvider.java:1084)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer.serializeWithType(JsonSerializer.java:159)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:695)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeWithType(BeanSerializerBase.java:566)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.TypeWrappedSerializer.serialize(TypeWrappedSerializer.java:32)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3559)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2927)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.JsonDataConverter.toData(JsonDataConverter.java:72)
> ... 8 more
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: 403 on a SOAP service? With JSON? Something is missing from your question. Are you mapping SOAP to JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson is trying to serialize some instance of [`com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/com/sun/xml/internal/ws/fault/ServerSOAPFaultException.java). This exception is a subclass of [`javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/xml/ws/soap/SOAPFaultException.java#SOAPFaultException), which [happens to have a getter for retrieving the `SOAPFault`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/xml/ws/soap/SOAPFaultException.java#SOAPFaultException.getFault%28%29). As a `SOAPFault` is a DOM `Node`, Jackson decides to use a `DOMSerializer` and also encode type information so that at deserialization time it can find out which concrete type `fault` was an instance of. The problem is that `DOMSerializer` does not support 
this type information thing, so you get `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException`.

I think the best way to work around this issue would be to register a custom serializer/deserializer pair for `SOAPFault`. You could then serialize to `String`s and deserialize creating new instances via one of the [`SOAPFactory.createFault(...)` methods](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/xml/soap/SOAPFactory.java#SOAPFactory.createFault%28java.lang.String%2Cjavax.xml.namespace.QName%29). Don't forget to also implement `JsonSerializer.serializeWithType(...)` so that Jackson can properly do type handling.

A (very rough) draft would be

```
public class SOAPFaultSerializer extends StdSerializer<SOAPFault> {

    public SOAPFaultSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public SOAPFaultSerializer(Class<SOAPFault> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(SOAPFault fault, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        jgen.writeStartObject();
        // serialize "interesting" SOAPFault information
        jgen.writeStringField("faultActor", fault.getFaultActor());
        jgen.writeStringField("faultCode", fault.getFaultCode());
        ...
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider, TypeSerializer typeSer) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
        typeSer.writeTypePrefixForObject(this, jgen, SOAPFault.class);
        serialize(value, jgen, provider);
        typeSer.writeTypeSuffixForObject(this, jgen);
    }
}

public class SOAPFaultDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<SOAPFault> { 

    public SOAPFaultDeserializer() { 
        this(null); 
    } 

    public SOAPFaultDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { 
         super(vc); 
    }

    @Override
    public SOAPFault deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
         JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
         // deserialize "interesting" SOAPFault information
         String faultActor = node.get("faultActor").asText();
         String faultCode = node.get("faultCode").asText();
         ...
         SOAPFactory factory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
         SOAPFault fault = factory.createFault();
         // fill in SOAPFault with deserialized fields
         fault.setFaultActor(faultActor);
         fault.setFaultCode(faultCode);
         ...
         return fault;
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `SOAPFactory.newInstance()` is likely to be relatively  expensive, so if you need to be performant you should try to call this method just once and reuse the factory instance.

Comment: Will do :) Thanks